# Is it possible that this vent is connected to the toilet drain and not to the stack?

Tags: plumbing

In the picture below I was told that in fact the yellow segment that you see at the bottom of the grey vent in actually connected to the toilet drain and not to the soil stack as depicted

I have seen diagrams where there was no vent there. My intention is to cut out the pipe as indicated in the diagram by the red arrows and to rebuild as described by the diagram. I am planning to leave the yellow piece in the ground and cap it and use it as an alternate clean out

[image]

Comment: anything is possible ... do you have any question that does not require guessing?

Comment: In the filed that I work in the very good professionals  stand out by their ability to interview the client and  get the best solution for his or her. If you feel there are missing details just ask. I do not omit details because I do not want to disclose them but because I do not have them or I don't realize you need them

Comment: Is this a drawing of your actual plumbing, your proposed new plumbing, some combination, or an idealized version of... something? Who told you about the condition of the yellow segment? Were the diagrams you've seen random drawings on the internet or diagrams of _your_ plumbing? You've posted a _ton_ of Qs (no problem there, very acceptable), but unless someone is intensely following _your_ progression, it's hard to keep up with them all. Also, it's a bit hard to tell where that yellow piece connects, can you add a zoomed in version?

Comment: green and purple are not there. The comments should explain what I want to do. I want to cut the grey pipe in the two indicated points and replace it with the green pipe. There is an option to eliminate the initial green segment from the grey pipe to the amber pipe and just run the amber pipe and eliminate the grey pipe completely. Green and/or purple will be there in the end state when I cut the grey pipe and I leave in the ground just the yellow segment that is the topic here

Comment: @MiniMe you asked `Is it possible that this vent is connected to the toilet drain and not to the stack?` ..... of course it is possible  .... no amount of guessing will change the actual point of connection ... you are the one who has to determine what is the reality

Comment: Of course it could be possible. The question is why would you do that when you already have a wet vent via the soil stack ..that is the part that I am trying to understand
Are they both needed. Will it work only with the soil stack? Will the green pipe in the middle of the picture play the role of a vent if I remove the grey one ?